MassTransit SQL Server database transport
I noticed that the documentation for the SQL Server database transport was updated not too long ago as well the samples (6 mos ago). I also noticed that the MassTransit.SqlTransport.SqlServer nuget package was published to nuget.org 3 months ago. Is this available for everyone to use now or do we still need a paid license?
I was hoping to use the SQL Server database transport for domain events and remove my dependency on Azure Service Bus.

It's regularly updated and is even used in the latest sample. It does not require a license to use.

Awesome thank you!
